# Разрезать строку на части

Tags: javascript, строки, методы

Нужно реализовать функцию splitString, которая принимает строку str, делит ее на части по 2 символа, а потом возвращает массив из полученных частей. Если строка содержит нечетное количество символов, нужно добавить подчеркивание к последнему символу _.

`splitString('ab cd ef'); // ['ab', ' c', 'd ', 'ef']`
`splitString('abc'); // ['ab', 'c_']`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Решение в лоб

```
function splitString(str){
    let rez = [];
    while(str.length>0){
        let str0 = '';
        let str1 = '';
        if(str[0]){
            str0 = str[0];
        }
        if(str[1]){
            str1 = str[1];
        }else{
            str1 = '_';
        }
        
        str = str.substr(2);
        rez .push(str0+str1)
    }

    console.log(rez);
    return rez;
}
splitString('ab cd efq');
```